# Hibernate: search with criteria not working as expected

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have entity "Bookmarks" with "keywords" (many to many) and "tags"(many to many). I want to find all bookmarks by keyword "k" -> `("k" belong to "keyords") || ("k" belong to "tags")`. This is the code:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Bookmark.class)
                .createAlias("tags", "tagsAlias")
                .createAlias("keywords", "keywordsAlias");

Disjunction  or = Restrictions.disjunction(
                Restrictions.like("tagsAlias.tagName", keyword + "%"),
                Restrictions.like("keywordsAlias.keyword", keyword + "%"));

criteria.add(or);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

List result = criteria.list();
```

With one criteria and one alias all is fine. But with two aliases the result is not correct - only subset of the correct output. Where I'm wrong?

Any help pointers appreciated .

Comment: What the the expected set, and what is the subset of it that you get as a result?

Comment: Hello,
Sorry for the late response. I can not see any connection between my expectations and the actual result. Perhaps because the data is too much. I did the task as did a separate `Criteria` for keywords and tags and then put them together in one `Set`. I know this is not a clean solution. On the other hand the code above seems correct and does not differ in logic and syntax of many examples that I watched. I wonder what the reason for not working. I tried to do the same with `hibernate search` and everything worked perfectly.